# How to get integers from a text file, using Python?

Tags: python

in Python I'm trying to set a variable from info stored in a txt. I can manage to set it, but it does not act as a number. Is it being stored as something else? 
Here is my .txt file (all info is written on one line, no \ns):

```
11 14 15 3
```

Here is my script:

```
def break_words(text):
    words = text.split(' ')
    return words

file_name = open("set_initial.txt")
words = break_words(file_name.read())

shift_l1 = words[0]
shift_l2 = words[1]
shift_l3 = words[2]
shift_l4 = words[3]
shift_l5 = words[4]
shift_l6 = words[5]

# this part is to verify that the variables are being set:
print shift_l1, shift_l2, shift_l3, shift_l4

while shift_l4 < 28:
# and the script goes on into a loop from here
```

I am using this method because the length of the values in the txt will change (for example to: 114 34 2 4318). When I run the script, the print function works fine and returns my variables as the numbers I have in my .txt (11 14 15 3 respectively), so shift_l4 prints out as 3, so my WHILE loop should be functioning. But it's not. As I said, I figure my variables aren't being set to the number value of the numbers in the .txt, but maybe just the text value? I don't know how to fix it though. Any help or ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"file_name" is not a good name for a file object. "words" is not a good name for a collection of numbers represented as strings. "shift_l5 = words[4]" and "shift_l6 = words[5]" will fail, because you have only 4 numbers.

Note that `print "3"` and `print 3` produce the same results. Use `print repr(something)` instead of just `print something` to get a handle on what data you actually have.

Try this:

```
f = open("set_initial.txt")
numbers = [int(n) for n in f.read().split()]
print numbers
assert len(numbers) == 4
shift_l1, shift_l2, shift_l3, shift_l4 = numbers
print shift_l1, shift_l2, shift_l3, shift_l4
```

Comment: Alright, I have a little reading to do on some of that, but it looks much more sensible, thank you. The script actually goes to shift_l8 and there's 12 sets of numbers in the txt, but I omitted it to make it simple. Sadly I forgot to omit shift_l5 & shift_l6 so I failed in that, hah. Thanks for the tips on names as well.

Comment: @user1042034 you should also choose an answer and close the question it will help get your question answered next time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have two different types in your comparison string and int. Assuming you are doing a numerical comparison you may want to explicitly cast your shift_l4 to an int. int(shift_l4).

Comment: Ah, of course. Changing it to shift_l1 = int(words[0]) etc. made it work. This seems like a really inefficient way to write a variable-length variable from a txt to a variable in a python script as I have to apply it to each individual iteration of words[x]. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @SteveRobillard: it's not a cast, it's a conversion. Python doesn't do casts.

Comment: @JohnMachin you are correct I sometime forget which language I am discussing and my pascal and basic roots show